# Android: Button's onClick Method not processed linearly?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I'm learning Android app coding and thought it would be a nice idea to code TicTacToe. So I got me six buttons aligned linearly in one activity, which change their color when clicked on, depending on the player's turn (orange or blue). The onClickListener's onClick method goes as follows:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{

    if(player == 1)
    {
        ((Button)v).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));

    }
    else
    {
        ((Button)v).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));

    }

    gameControl();
}
```

gameControl follows with the game basics: Check if a player won, if it is a draw or not etc.:

```
    public void gameControl()

     if(checkForWin())
     {
         playerWins(player);
     }
     else if(round == 9)
     {
         draw();
     }
     else
     {
         if(player == 1)
             player = 2;
         else
             player = 1;
     }

     round++;
 }
```

My problem is that if a player won, that is if the last button to win the game is clicked, the button's color won't change. Rather, the playerWins method (in gameControl) refreshes the "playfield" before the button's color changes. I've tried stuff like Handler.postDelayed and such because it seems like the entire onClick methods is run through before the button's color is addressed, but no success there. Why is the onClick method not processed linearly? Is there any way to refresh the activity or something? Thanks in advance ...

Thanks for the quick response, here are the requested methods:

```
private void playerWins(int player)
{
    if(player == 1)
    {
        player1Points++;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
        round = 1;
    }

    if(player == 2)
    {
        player2Points++;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Player 2 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
        round = 1;
    }
}
```

The resetBoard method:

```
private void resetBoard()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B0C4DE"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I may need to add that i've also tried writing text to each button that is clicked. In that case, the last button shows the text when the message "Player x won" is shown and the playfield is refreshed afterwards. So I don't think that the refreshing of the playfiled is just to quick for me to notice the changing of color of the respective button.

Comment: Can you post the playerWins method too? You may not see the color change if you are refreshing immediately. It would not be "eye detectable" because of the speed it changes

Comment: Hi Lenin, I just updated my post.

Comment: Hi @amateur, where did you put the `postDelayed` ?

Comment: Lenin is correct. There's nothing in your code that will block or pause execution before the board is reset, and the backgrounds are set to the default color. It is running "linearly", but it's just happening too quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is happening to quickly i guess and that's why you are not seeing it. You have a some approaches:

1- Putting a refresh button somewhere and only refresh when it is clicked (This option would be good for example if users know it will be a draw and they want to start again before finishing). So with this option you will not reset before user see the update.

2- Showing an AlertDialog to say "Player X wins!" and when user press OK you reset the board. It would be something like

```
AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context);
dialog.setTitle("Your title");
dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      resetBoard()
   }
 });
dialog.setCancellable(false);
dialog.show();
```

Also just check you can reduce some code refactoring, as you are repeating code. For example playerWins() could be

```
private void playerWins(int player){

  if(player == 1)
  {
      player1Points++;
      Toast.makeText(this,"Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  if(player == 2)
  {
    player2Points++;
    Toast.makeText(this,"Player 2 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  updatePointsText();
  resetBoard();
  round = 1;
}
```

Comment: Great approch and worked well for me. Thanks for the effort!